# javascript function disables variable in div from being send , how to stop that

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
$('[data-toggle="wizard-radio"]').click(function() {
    wizard = $(this).closest('.wizard-card');
    wizard.find('[data-toggle="wizard-radio"]').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(wizard).find('[type="checkbox"]').removeAttr('checked');
    $(this).find('[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked','true');
})
```

This code is somehow disabling the variable from being sent so I can get it with `$_POST` array on the server side

Any idea how to activate it to send when submitting

Comment: What is your HTML?

Comment: <div class="choice" data-toggle="wizard-radio"> 
              <div class=" btn-next   " hidden>

                                                  <input type="checkbox" name="Great" value="Great" >
                      <div class="card card-checkboxes card-hover-effect">
                                                      <i class="ti-face-smile"></i>
               <p style="font-weight: bold;">Great</p>

Comment: Put the HTML in the question itself, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These 2 lines needed help

```
$(wizard).find('[type="checkbox"]').removeAttr('checked');
$(this).find('[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked','true');
```

the correct method for checkboxes is `.prop('checked', true/false)`

Also I removed the `hidden` attribute since it was making things invisible. Did you need that in there?

```js
$('[data-toggle="wizard-radio"]').click(function() {
  wizard = $(this).closest('.wizard-card');
  wizard.find('[data-toggle="wizard-radio"]').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $(wizard).find('[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
  $(this).find('[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
})
```

```css
.active {
  color: #f00;
}

.card-checkboxes {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wizard-card'>
  <div class="choice" data-toggle="wizard-radio">
    <div class=" btn-next " hidden>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Great" value="Great">
      <div class="card card-checkboxes card-hover-effect">
        <i class="ti-face-smile"></i>
        <p style="font-weight: bold;">Great</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="choice" data-toggle="wizard-radio">
    <div class=" btn-next ">
      <input type="checkbox" name="soso" value="Soso">
      <div class="card card-checkboxes card-hover-effect">
        <i class="ti-face-smile"></i>
        <p style="font-weight: bold;">So-so</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you , Solved it , i needed the hidden attribute but it still works with hidden attribute ...I mean your solution solved it